# How to setup Drupal multi language site?

Tags: drupal-7, multilingual

I was searched and read many websites but can't find how to set up drupal multi language website.

I want to use 2 languages in a site.

These 2 languages have **different content**. (not content translation).

I had enabled Locale module, enabled multilingual support in each content type

but when i was added content in 2 languages

the front page list all of those articles without filter the site's language.

how to setup drupal 7 to list articles with filtered language.

eg: 
http://example.com/en <- this url should list all english article.
http://example.com/fr <- this url should list all france article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to install **i18n** or [**Internationalization**](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module from Drupal contributed modules and enabled these option.

- Multilingual select
- Internationalization

** This module require [Variable](http://drupal.org/project/variable) module.

Answer (score 0):

Since the content is different, one way to achieve this is by creating two different content types. Assign an alias pattern to each content type like en/[node:title] and fr/[node:title]. You can then display each or both content types on any page; it could be a taxonomy page with alias en or fr. If you choose this method you won't need locale. This one is not intended for translated sites where each content has a matching translated content.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to expand some special words which have not include in language lib, you can try following code:

```
$zh = variable_get('locale_custom_strings_zh-hans');//zh-hans is your language key.
$zh["More news"] = '更多信息'; //  KEY/VALUE
variable_set('locale_custom_strings_zh-hans',$zh); // set it back.
```